# Python getting minimum date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data structure which I am using pandas where i am getting the minimum data for a plan. So the data structure looks as below

```
Engagement ID     Plan Start Date
A                  17-7-2017
A                  18-7-2017
A                  20-7-2017
```

I am trying to achieve this

```
Engagement ID     Plan Start Date   Earliest Plan start date
A                  17-7-2017         17-7-2017
A                  18-7-2017         17-7-2017
A                  20-7-2017         17-7-2017
```

I was able to do it like this

```
engagement_df_earliest_plan_date = engagement_df.loc[engagement_df.groupby('Engagement Id', sort=False)['Plan Start Date'].idxmin()]
engagement_df_earliest_plan_date = engagement_df_earliest_plan_date[['Engagement Id','Plan Start Date']];
engagement_df_earliest_plan_date = engagement_df_earliest_plan_date.rename(columns={'Plan Start Date': 'Earliest Plan Start Date'});
```

But i feel this is not elegant enough and was wondering is there a better way to do things?

Comment: How about something like `df.groupby("Engagement ID")['Plan Start Date'].transform('first')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a slightly bigger sample -

```
df

  Engagement ID Plan Start Date
0             A       17-7-2017
1             A       18-7-2017
2             A       20-7-2017
3             B       21-7-2017
4             B       22-7-2017
5             C       29-7-2017
6             C       30-7-2017
```

If needed, convert to datetime using `pd.to_datetime` -

```
df['Plan Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Plan Start Date'], errors='coerce')
```

Now, to get your desired output, `groupby` the first column, and `transform` with respect to the `first` row in each group -

```
df['Earliest Plan Start Date'] = \
       df.groupby("Engagement ID")['Plan Start Date'].transform('first')
df

  Engagement ID Plan Start Date Earliest Plan Start Date
0             A      2017-07-17               2017-07-17
1             A      2017-07-18               2017-07-17
2             A      2017-07-20               2017-07-17
3             B      2017-07-21               2017-07-21
4             B      2017-07-22               2017-07-21
5             C      2017-07-29               2017-07-29
6             C      2017-07-30               2017-07-29
```

However, this might not be ideal, since the first date might not always be the smallest one. For that purpose, you might consider a slightly different alternative, using `nsmallest` + `map` -

```
v = df.groupby("Engagement ID", group_keys=False)['Plan Start Date'].nsmallest(1)
v.index = v.index.droplevel(1)
```

```
df['Earliest Plan Start Date'] = df['Engagement ID'].map(v)
```

Or,

```
df['Earliest Plan Start Date'] = df['Engagement ID'].replace(v)
```

```
df

  Engagement ID Plan Start Date Earliest Plan Start Date
0             A      2017-07-17               2017-07-17
1             A      2017-07-18               2017-07-17
2             A      2017-07-20               2017-07-17
3             B      2017-07-21               2017-07-21
4             B      2017-07-22               2017-07-21
5             C      2017-07-29               2017-07-29
6             C      2017-07-30               2017-07-29
```

Now, you guarantee the earliest date. Note that `v` looks like this -

```
v

Engagement ID
A   2017-07-17
B   2017-07-21
C   2017-07-29
Name: Plan Start Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```